# UTF-8 solution file save unexpected

Tags: asp.net, utf-8

I am developing a webpage and every time I hit save all it brings up this save dialog. It has does this every time and I have rebuilt this page three times trying to get it to stop. What is causing it and how can I correct this unexpected event.

[image: Issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typically occurs when opening the visual studio project as a web application or web site that never had the solution file created. By default the visual studio wants to have a solution file with it. Until you click "save" it will keep bothering you. Once you tell it "save" it will not bother you anymore and there is no harm in have the project associated to a solution file.